# How come Nova's dad could talk?

Tags: plot-explanation, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

In [War for the Planet of the Apes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3450958/), the Colonel is trying to avoid the spread of the disease which turns talking humans to non-talking beasts. In fact, by the end of the movie,

> simple contact with Nova's doll makes him ill and unable to talk

However, Nova's dad ran from the soldier group months ago, but is still able to speak. When Ceaser & crew show up, he says:

> I'm just going to put these sticks down.

It takes a day for the Colonel to be sick, but her dad is just fine after maybe months. Is this a plot-hole or is there any particular reason?

Comment: Wikia says that her dad was one of the three shot in the snow, and that the soldier that was at the cabin was experimenting on Nova. Or he was a caretaker, someone sympathetic to the situation.

Comment: @cde Would you flesh out an answer quoting the wiki? I will if you dont, it seems to be the better answer

Comment: My reply was deleted by some unwarranted reason. I hope you got what I said.

Answer (score 2):

No particular reason is given.

Many humans are naturally resistant to some diseases. The survivors we see in the 2nd movie and 3rd movie, are all immune to simian flu. Her dad could have some resistance or immunity to the disease.

We don't know how the disease spreads. It might spread only via blood (like HIV), which could just mean her dad was careful not to touch her blood, or just lucky.

Comment: There's some belief that that wasn't even her dad. That whole plot point is very confusing now.

Comment: Replace "the dad" with his title, name, etc, an it still works, since all I'm doing is guesswork.